# Implementing Internationalization of Japanese with Spanish language is not working

Tags: java, spring

The below code we added in servlet.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="fileEncodings" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:messages</value>
            <value>classpath:labels</value>
            <value>classpath:errors</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

**and in JSP we added like below**

page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"

by adding like above code japanese language is working but spanish is not working, if we replace "UTF-8" with "ISO-8859-1" Spanish language is working.

Can anyone help me how to make it work both japanese and spanish languages in our spring application?

Comment: UTF8 supports all languages. How do you deliver the Spanish content?

Answer (score 0):

Your Spanish properties files are saved in ISO-8859-1 format instead of in UTF-8 format. Load them into an editor that can open and save in multiple formats (I use Babelpad) to see if this is the case.